# Xcode 6 autolayout issues

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

So I am trying to achieve a layout like the below picture. But have trouble with `Autolayout`.

I have managed to get the left `ImageView` showing and the 5 `Labels`, but the right `ImageView` is getting cut off and not showing at all.

Label constraints:
- all 5 are equal width
- the top have top space to container
- bottom have bottom space to container
- all of them have trailing and leading space to both ImageViews
- vertical spacing between each label

Left ImageView constraints:
- height
- leading space
- top space
- bottom space

Right ImageView constraints:
- height
- trailing space
- top space
- bottom space

[image]

Comment: Please include the document outline in your screenshot.

Comment: @TheNomad The constraints depends on if you wan't your both image views of fixed height and with or variable?

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh I would want to the ImageViews to be variable height and width. Would want it to scale down/up correctly.

Comment: @dasdom how do I include the document outline? Is that the constraints in the right hand side window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to set the height of the image views due to top and bottom margins you have set

I would setup this as follows:

1. Left image view: top, leading left, bottom, width
2. Right image view: top, trailing right, bottom, width
3. Labels: top, leading left to left image view, trailing right to right image view >= 8

This fixes the images and lets the label widths be flexible.

Comment: Depends whether the image views define the height of the table view cell. Key word: self-sizing cells

Comment: @zisoft how would I go about make the `ImageViews` variable? but to keep the same aspect ratio?

Comment: Ctrl-drag on an image view and choose "Aspect Ratio". Set further constraints on them to achieve the margins and so on. This really depends on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to get the Perfect Auto layout is by choosing the option "Reset to suggested constraints".
Goto Interface builder => Select the View => Look at the bottom Right => Click the Third icon => Choose "Reset to suggested constraints"

Comment: Not really. How should Xcode know what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't turn out the way I want to.